# Options passed to create have invalid parent?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to use Knockout.mapping in conjunction with Knockout.validation to create a simple validated view model. I came across the `create` function in `ko.mapping` and thought that would suit my needs but it seems that the options.parent property isn't set to what I'd expect:

This is the basic code that I'm using or you can see a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/5KJYg/).

```
var o = {
    test: {
        value: "bob",
        validation: "{ required: true; }"
    }
};
var mapping = {
    'value': {
        create: function (options) {
            console.log(options.parent === o.test);
        }
    }
};

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(o, mapping);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? My ultimate aim is I want to call something along the following lines in create:

```
create: function(options) {
   var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
   if(options.parent.validation !== undefined) {
       result.extend(options.parent.validation); 
   }

   return result;
}
```

If this is just broken can anyone think of any relatively simple ways around the problem? The only solution I've come up with so far is a recursive property search to manually extend the observables which feels like a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in my project was add an `id` to check the parent, like this:

```
var o = {
    test: {
        id: "1",
        value: "bob",
        validation: "{ required: true; }"
    }
};
var mapping = {
    'value': {
        create: function (options) {
            console.log(options.parent.id() === o.test.id);
        }
    }
};
```

Test **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/5KJYg/2/)**

Comment: I tried debugging this before I started, to verify I've added the following line `console.log('validation : ' + options.parent.validation);` which logs `undefined`

Comment: Its because option.parent is the mapped object not the orginal data. And it maps them in the same order they were declared, value is defined before validation

Comment: @Anders: Ok, that explains why the validation attribute's missing, and means I can probably change the create on validation to extend the value instead.

Comment: I would use my approuch but add the validation dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create explicit ViewModels and then use the mapping plugin to populate them like

```
ViewModel = function(data) {
   this.value = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
   ko.mapping.fromJS(this, {}, data);
};
```

Comment: this is a very simplistic example to demonstrate the issue. I can't explicitly extend the value like this as the fields are created dynamically.